# ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 3, the array at index 0 has size 3

Tags: python, numpy, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Если нужно могу приложить Jupyter Notebook и папку с файлами (там изображения).

Код:

```
def define_discriminator(in_shape = (106, 106, 1)):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides = (2,2), padding = "same", input_shape = in_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides = (2,2), padding = "same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
    opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0002, beta_1 = 0.5)
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics = ["accuracy"])
    return model
def define_generator(latent_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    n_nodes = 128 * 53 * 53
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim = latent_dim))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Reshape((53, 53, 128)))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1024, (4,4), strides = (2,2), padding = "same"))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Conv2D(1, (7,7), padding = "same", activation = "sigmoid"))
    return model
def define_gan(g_model, d_model):
    d_model.trianabel = False
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(g_model)
    model.add(d_model)
    opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0002, beta_1 = 0.5)
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt)
    return model
def generate_real_samples(dataset, n_samples):
    ix = randint(0, dataset.shape[0], n_samples)
    X = dataset[ix].T
    Y = ones((n_samples, 1)).T
    return X, Y

def generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_samples):
    x_input = randn(latent_dim * n_samples)
    x_input = x_input.reshape(n_samples, latent_dim)
    return x_input

def generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, n_samples):
    x_input = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_samples)
    X = g_model.predict(x_input).T
    Y = zeros((n_samples, 1)).T
    return X, Y

import tensorflow as tf
def train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs=51, n_batch=10):
    bat_per_epo = int(dataset.shape[0] / n_batch)
    half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        for j in range(bat_per_epo):
            X_real, y_real = generate_real_samples(dataset, half_batch)
            X_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, half_batch)
            print(X_real, X_fake)
            print(y_real, y_fake)
            X, y = vstack((X_real, X_fake)), vstack((y_real, y_fake))
            d_loss, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X, y)
            X_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_batch)
            y_gan = ones((n_batch, 1))
            g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(X_gan, y_gan)
            print('>%d, %d/%d, d=%.3f, g=%.3f' % (i+1, j+1, bat_per_epo, d_loss, g_loss))
        if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
            summarize_performance(i, g_model, d_model, dataset, latent_dim)
            clear_output()

latent_dim = 100
d_model = define_discriminator()
g_model = define_generator(latent_dim)
gan_model = define_gan(g_model, d_model)
print(pixels.shape)
train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, np.array(pixels), latent_dim)<code lang="python">
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------- -------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-482-b3360c520333> in <module>
      4 gan_model = define_gan(g_model, d_model)
      5 print(pixels.shape)
----> 6 train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, np.array(pixels), 
latent_dim)

<ipython-input-481-051ded2aca77> in train(g_model, d_model, 
gan_model, 
dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs, n_batch)
      9             print(X_real, X_fake)
     10             print(y_real, y_fake)
---> 11             X, y = vstack((X_real, X_fake)), vstack((y_real, 
y_fake))
     12             d_loss, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X, y)
     13             X_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, 
n_batch)

<__array_function__ internals> in vstack(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\envs\LikeProject\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py 
in vstack(tup)
    281     if not isinstance(arrs, list):
    282         arrs = [arrs]
--> 283     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    284 
    285 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis 
must match exactly, but along dimension 3, the array at index 0 has 
size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

Comment: похоже у вас в строке `d_loss, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X, y)` число экземпляров в `X` -> 4, а в `y` -> 2, о чем вам и сообщают. Так обучить модель не получится)

Comment: Когда я сравниваю количество экземпляров мне выдаёт следующее: (добавил скрин к вопросу).

Comment: @MaxU Я обновил код и решил проблему, но теперь возникла другая, можете посмотреть, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала разнесите `X, y = vstack((X_real, X_fake)), vstack((y_real,  y_fake))` на две строки, чтобы понять в каком из `vstack()` возникает данная ошибка.

После этого сравните размерности объединяемых матриц. Ошибка явно указывает на то что все размерности (кроме числа экземпляров) должны совпадать.

Например мы хотим объединить тензор цветных картинок размерностью `(10000, 120, 120, 3)` (10.000 цветных картинок разрешения 120x120 x3 цветовых канала) с тензором цветных картинок размерностью `(4000, 120, 120, 3)` (4.000 цветных картинок разрешения 120x120 x3 цветовых канала) и в итоге мы получим тензор размерностью `(14000, 120, 120, 3)`. Обратите внимание что размерности по осям 1, 2, 3 совпадают - `(120, 120, 3)`. Т.е. наши тензоры это собранные воедино трехразмерные матрицы (где каждая 3D маитрица представляет собой одну картинку размерности 120x120 и имеет три цветовых канала: RGB) и все эти картинки (трехмерные матрицы) собрали вместе и получили четырехразмерную матрицу (тензор) размерности `(N, 120, 120, 3)`
, где `N` - число картинок.

Очевидно в вашем случае это не так.

Comment: Когда я привожу их к одному размеру, мне выдает следующее: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_414 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (4, 106, 106, 5) . Я понимаю, что это значит, но не совсем понимаю как дать модели нужный размер. Или может нужно изменить размер матрицы(только как)?

Comment: @Lorandius, StackOverflow так не работает) Вы пытаетесь в одном вопросе решить все свои проблемы. Вы уже получили ответы на два своих вопроса в этом топике. Если у вас возник новый вопрос - примите те ответы, которые помогли вам решить предыдущие проблемы и откройте новый вопрос

Comment: Так и поступлю)